# Bootstrap Spacing Helper at Different Viewports?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, spacing

I have the following code.

```html
<section class="visit-section mb-7 mt-7 mb-sm-3 mt-sm-3 nb-md-5">
</section>
```

In the developer tools in Firefox, when I select the element with the picker, it doesn't seem to be recognizing the class mb-sm-3 or mt-sm-3. In other words, the spacing that it is adding is from mb-7 and mt-7. After looking for 30 minutes, I'm not entirely sure why this is happening. :-\

Did I understand it wrong from the Bootstrap 4 manual?
[Bootstrap Manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you have should be working well, but a couple things I noticed on you code that are preventing it to function properly:

- Bootstrap's spacing utilities go from `0` to `5`, as in `mb-0 | mb-5`, there's no `mb-7` unless you specify so yourself. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#notation)
- Keep in mind that `sm` breakpoint applies to smartphones in landscape orientation; so maybe you are not triggering the correct breakpoint yet

If you try the code below in full screen, you can see that the margins actually change when you resize the browser window; all I did to your code was changing the `mb-7` classes to `mb-5` and fix a typo on the last class you had as well

```css
section {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="visit-section mb-5 mt-5 mb-sm-3 mt-sm-3 mb-md-5">
</section>

<section class="visit-section mb-5 mt-5 mb-sm-3 mt-sm-3 mb-md-5">
</section>
```